# Periodically store changes of shared workbook into an isolated workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, a shared "xlsx" file A which stores data and no-sharing "xlsm" file B which contains my macros. I would like maintain periodic  tracking of changes in file A and password-protect this change history. I know there is a "Track Changes" feature in file A and it could create a separate sheet containing the change history. However, this sheet is within workbook A, which is being shared. Is there a way to write a macro in B to periodically extract this change history from A, put it into a "xlsx" file C with password?

The point here is I would like to prevent the change history to be compromised. Only I have access to it. Note that I can not make file A "macro enabled" and write macro in it.

Thank.

Comment: Can you just hide the sheet with the tracked changes so nobody knows that it exists?  If that is not a valid action then it would not be too hard to just copy the contents of that sheet to another workbook.

Comment: Thanks, NinjaLlama. The "Track changes" feature needs to be activated by the person using file A. And when that person saves and closes file A, this sheet containing the change history will disappear as well (Although if you open file A again and activate "Track Changes", you will get the same change history. My difficulty lies in writing a code in file B to open file A and activate "Track Changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the Shared WB, update the change info, then copy the History sheet

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wbShared As Workbook
    Dim wbHistory As Workbook

    Set wbHistory = Application.Workbooks.Open( _
      Filename:="\\Path\To\Your\History\FileC.xlsx", _
      Password:="Password")

    Set wbShared = Application.Workbooks.Open( _
      FileName:="\\Path\To\Your\Shared\FileA.xlsx")

    ' Generate History Sheet (maybe change xlAllChanges to suit needs)
    With wbShared
        .HighlightChangesOptions _
          When:=xlAllChanges, _
          Who:="Everyone"
        .ListChangesOnNewSheet = True
    End With

    ' Copy out History to FileC
    wbShared.Worksheets("History").Copy After:=wbHistory.Sheets(wbHistory.Sheets.Count)

    ' Clean Up
    wbShared.Close False
    wbHistory.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for answering. I have found a solution some time back. Very similar to your advice here !

Answer (score 0):

Using your private workbook, you can use macros to open the shared workbook and copy the sheet into the private workbook again.

EDIT: Sorry, I missed the part about saving it into a file C.

Here is to get you started:

```
Sub wbCopy()
    Dim sharedWb, myWb As Workbook
    Dim sharedWs As Worksheet

    Set myWb = New Workbook

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="192.168.0.10\sharedWorkbook.xls", ReadOnly:=True
    Set sharedWb = "sharedWorkbook.xls"
    Set sharedWs = sharedWb.Worksheets(2)

    sharedWs.Copy myWb.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

    Workbooks("sharedWorkbook.xls").Close

    myWb.SaveAs Filename:="File C.xls"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vegard. Similar to my reply to NinjaLlama, the problem is with the "Track Changes" feature in file A. It needs to be activated manually when while file A is being open. Once file A is saved, this sheet containing the change history is gone. So if I use code in file B to open file A, there is no "Change history" sheet there. I would like to use code to activate it from file B.

Comment: Directly answering your question is beyond the scope I can contribute in. Part of me doubts that it is possible using "native" tools alone. I wrote a manual diff tool for excel files, however... if you'd be content with comparing "before" and "after" versions of the file, it's easily accomplished using only simple VBA.

Comment: Actually, I don't know why I assumed that you can't put macros into file A. Can you put macros into file A?

Comment: File A is a shared file. Anyone who know macros can compromise my Change History. Furthermore, if someone turns off the "Track Changes" feature while opening file A, the change history before this access is wiped out, even if that person turns it on back before saving the file. This, again, compromises the Change History.

Comment: Also, file A is a corporate-wide shared file. Making it a macro file may pose unpredictable problems in the future.

Comment: Also, comparing "before" and "after" was also on my mind. But I need to implement this action to unforeseeable number of files with large sizes (in the order or MegaByte). Periodically duplicating these files (daily, at least) will exhaust the resource pretty soon.

Comment: You can password protect the VBA portion of a file. This will prevent anyone from changing your code or adding new code. I bet you can also use VBA to prevent the change history from being disabled, but I don't (yet) know how.